# Error: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier

Tags: smartcontracts, remix, erc721

I have a deployed contract. Now I want to make changes through the Remix, but there was some kind of error. please help me to solve this error. thanks.

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
**pragma solidity ^0.8.10;**

import "erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

**Error: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
-->**

I tried changing **compiler** but it didn't help

Comment: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
--> contracts/Worldtanktest.sol:48:49:
|
48 | return(string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, Strings.toString(tokenId+1), ".json" )));
| ^^^^^^^

Comment: Could you please provide us with the complete code of the smart contract? I also want to clarify regarding making changes to a deployed contract. Unless you specifically designed the contract to be modifiable, such as by implementing proxies, making changes to the contract will require redeploying a new version with the desired modifications